# Hacer INNER JOIN de una clave foranea

Tags: postgresql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como hago para ver la descripción del departamento mediante una consulta SQL que llama a todos los registros de personas?

Esta es la consulta que llevo

```
SELECT p.nombre, p.apellido1, p.apellido2, p.dep 
FROM personas p, departamentos d 
WHERE p.dep = d.dep
```

Comment: nos muestras que has intentado? tengo una respuesta pero es necesario coloques que llevas

Comment: tienes algún avance de lo que has intentado?

Comment: Necesitas un Join.  Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: Uso postgres como base de datos. La consulta que tengo hasta ahora es: `SELECT p.nombre, p.apellido1, p.apellido2, p.dep FROM personas p, departamentos d WHERE p.dep = d.dep`

Comment: mira los graficos que tiene[wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join) explicando los distintos JOINS que existen

Comment: Necesito que la consulta me muestre la descripcion de los `departamentos` relacionándolos con el dep de `personas`

Answer (score 2):

Debes hacerlo a través del uso de `JOIN` pues estas tratando de vincular 2 tablas; una de ellas por su `PK` que es `dep` y otra por su `FK` en personas que es `dep`

```
SELECT departamentos.departamento, personas.nombre, personas.apellido1
FROM departamentos
INNER JOIN personas ON departamentos.dep = personas.dep;
```

La consulta anterior buscará la coincidencia en ambas tablas y te mostrará las columnas que tu explicitamente indiques requieres

**EL USO DE INNER JOIN**

> La unión y posteriores resultados que nos devuelve estarán
>   condicionados a que tanto en la tabla de la izquierda que
>   es(departamentos), como en la de la derecha que es(personas) existan
>   registros vinculados, omitiendo aquellos registros que solo existen en
>   una de las 2 tablas pero no en ambas

Answer (score 1):

dices tener la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT p.nombre, p.apellido1, p.apellido2, p.dep FROM personas p, departamentos d WHERE p.dep = d.dep
```

considero que para enlazar tu tabla lo que requiere es un join para que puedas acceder desde tu consulta a los atributos de tu tabla

podrias hacer algo como esto

```
SELECT p.nombre, p.apellido1, p.apellido2, p.dep, d.ped as relacion, d.descripcion 
FROM personas p
inner join departamento d on d.ped = p.dep
WHERE p.dep = d.dep
```

Comment: si usa el **inner join** para que después el uso de **where** ? no con eso estas siendo redundante?

Comment: es una alternativa, en ocasiones las condiciones pueden variar, por esto la añadi. Tu decides si usarlas o no segun sea el caso

Comment: pero es que ya en la condición del `ON` estas haciendo la igualación, por eso además hacer esa misma igualación en el `WHERE` es repetir ese mismo paso

Answer (score 0):

Lo he conseguido de esta manera:

```
SELECT p.nombre, p.apellido1, p.apellido2, *d.departamento*`
FROM personas p, departamentos d
WHERE p.dep = d.dep
```

Solo llamo a la descripcion del departamento.

No sé si ha esto le considera `JOIN`, pero me funciona perfectamente.
Gracias a todos.

Comment: es un join implicito, pero deberías usar uno explicito, ya que tu gestor te permite usarlo

Comment: esa consulta hace lo siguiente trae todos los datos personas, luego trae todos los datos departamentos , y  al final filtra, en conclusion es muy lento, si cambias a inner join  va a buscar exclusivamente los datos relacionados